# How to write unit tests for function that reads and writes to STDIO in GO?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have a function in GO that takes input from stdio and writes to stdio. Is there a way to write unit tests for the function?

An example function is:

```
func double() {
    var in int
    _, err = fmt.Scanf("%d", &in)
    if err==nil{
        fmt.Scanf(2*in)
    }
    else{
        log.Fatal("Error Scanning input")
    }
}
```

Note that in the real function I want to test, the I/O spans several lines so its not just as simple as making the result as an integer and return it. I am just giving the example here for reference.

Comment: You don't unit test stdin, you make your implementation testable and independent from stdin.

Comment: Specifically, have the function take in an `io.Reader`, use `fmt.Fscanf`, and then pass it either stdin or an appropriate test Reader as necessary.

Comment: @Adrian I am fairly new to GO. Do you mind giving me a reference where to start with these classes?

Comment: I highly recommend reading the friendly manual: https://golang.org/pkg/io and https://golang.org/pkg/fmt would cover the interface and function I mentioned.